# Conditional Break point at Multiple hitcount Times in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2012, breakpoints, visual-studio-debugging

How can I set the breakpoint to be hit on multiple hitcounts.

[image]

Like in above figure I want it to be hit at times when the hit count is 234 ,345,567,1234 ,2314 etc.

It doesn't allow me to put a comma as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *CAN* set "when breakpoint is a multiple of the counter".  In your example, this would be "234,  468, 702, ...":

- [MSDN: Breakpoint Hit Count Dialog Box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290719%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Q: Is that sufficient?

Q: If not, is there any specific reason (besides sheer perverseness) you'd need a different hit count each breakpoint?

ONE OTHER ALTERNATIVE:

If you wanted, you can you can keep your own counter, and programatically invoke a break in C# any time you want:

- [MSDN: System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: the reason why I want a different hit count each breakpoint is I know at these points I have some testpoints in my f/w running on some microcontroller with which my C# application is interacting over serial interface.So I want the execution to be stopped at those points and check in the f/w. I prefer the second way you suggested.Thanks !